# Custom field Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a reference from my Devise `User` model to my `Organisation` model.

I want to be able to create Organisations with whatever name the user enters in the signup page if that organisation name doesn't exist. If, however, the user enters an existing Organisiation's name, I just need to assign the reference to that User's model.

As I said, I've created the migration and I know how to add the field to my signup page's view but I'm not sure how to get devise to conditionally create the Organisation or just add a reference to it when the user signs up.

Comment: what is the relationship between your User model and Organization model

Comment: `User` has a Organisation:reference field. `Organisation` has_many `User`s and each `User` belongs_to an `Organisation`. Organisations do not theoretically need Users but Users need to be associated with an organisation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For posterity, this is what my `registrations_controller.rb` looked like in the end (or thereabouts):

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  # POST /resource
  def create
    super do |resource|
      resource.organization = Organization.find_or_create_by(:organization_name => params[:user][:organization_attributes][:organization_name])
    end
  end
end
```

Using `before_filter` as suggested by Hoa was making Devise try to create new Organizations which resulted in duplicates. I added a uniqueness validation to the `Organization` Model which only stopped new registrations to preexisting Organizations. This solution hops in on the block exposed in Devise's create method (see [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb)). It really helps to "go to the source".

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to customize devise registration, do the following

Generate registration code

```
$ rails generate devise:controllers users registrations
$ rails generate devise:views users registrations
```

Add to `routes.rb`

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
  registrations: "users/registrations"
}
```

I assume you know how to add a nested attribute called organization to your signup form. Anyway, if you use Rails `form_for`, it's something like this

```
<%= f.fields_for :organization, Organization.new do |org_fields| %>
  <%= org_fields.text_field :name %>
<% end %>
```

In `users/registrations_controller.rb`, apply the following updates

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]

  # POST /resource
  def create
    super
    resource.organization = Organization.find_or_create_by(name: sign_up_params[:organization_attributes][:name])
  end

  protected

    def configure_sign_up_params
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << [ organization_attributes: [ :name ] ]
    end 

  ...
end
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: That looks awesome, I'm away right now but I'll accept and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: `Organization.find_or_create_by` keeps creating a new Organization in my program (never returning an existing Organization). If I use `find_or_create_by` in the rails console it works as expected though. Any idea why that would happen?

Comment: @j3frea What is your RegistrationsController#create looks like?

Comment: All I have in users/registrations_controller.rb is what you gave me here so in `create` it's just `super` and the `find_or_create_by` line - it's working in that it creates a new Org with the correct name (no weird characters or anything) but obviously it should be finding the existing one.

Comment: I figured out the problem, see my answer below